# flow entry with empty actions set in Mininet with more than one switch and POX controller

Tags: openflow, mininet, pox

I'm using Mininet and POX controller. The network topology has multiple switches.
Whenever I install flow for some switch, and afterwards I check the flow table in that switch, its actions set is empty.
dump-flows shows `actions=`
However, when there's only one switch in the network, the actions set is not empty.
What may be the reason for the actions set being empty ?

Thank you

Comment: How are you adding the flows? Can you show some code of how you add the flows, or if you're doing it via the web service, can you show what you're doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking in OpenFlow specifications again, 
I learned that an empty actions set in a flow entry is a *drop* flow.

From [OpenFlow Switch Specifications v1.3.1](https://www.opennetworking.org/images/stories/downloads/sdn-resources/onf-specifications/openflow/openflow-spec-v1.3.1.pdf)

> **Drop.** There is no explicit action to represent drops. Instead, packets whose action
>   sets have no output actions should be dropped.

Afterwards, I realized where was the error in the code which made the incorrect flow entry installed.